# How to get Docker container ID alone

Tags: docker, containers

I have only one docker instance running. My actual task to write shell script around this container.

However the first step is to get the container ID via a shell command.

Is there a shell command to do it?

Answer (score 15):

you can do either

`docker ps -q`

or also, as the only running container is also the last one

`docker ps -lq`